# Android parsing nested JsonArray warning on Logcat

Tags: android, json, android-listview, arrays

I have a class to parsing the nested jsonarray. I've been able to show the json data. This is how i parsing the nested json

```
private static String DIV_ID = "DivisionID";
private static String DIV_NAME = "DivisionName";
private static String SUBDIV_ID = "SubDivisionID";
private static String SUBDIV_NAME = "SubDivisionName";
private static String TAG_NOPOL = "Nopol";
private static String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static String TAG_LONG = "LastLon";

public String getDivisionID() {
    return DIV_ID;
}
public void setDivID (String divisionId) {
    this.DIV_ID = divisionId;
}
public String getDivisionName()
{
    return DIV_NAME;
}
public void setDivName(String divisionName)
{
    this.DIV_NAME = divisionName;
}
public String getSubdivID() {
    return SUBDIV_ID;
}
public void setSubdivID(String subdivisionId) {
    this.SUBDIV_ID = subdivisionId;
}
public String getSubdivName() {
    return SUBDIV_NAME;
}
public void setSubdivName(String SubdivisionName) {
    this.SUBDIV_NAME = SubdivisionName;
}
public String getnoPol() {
    return TAG_NOPOL;
}
public void setnoPol (String nopol) {
    this.TAG_NOPOL = nopol;
}
public String getLocate() {
    return TAG_LOCATION;
}
public void setLocate(String location) {
    this.TAG_LOCATION = location;
}
public String getLastlon() {
    return TAG_LONG;
}
public void setLastlon(String lastlon) {
    this.TAG_LONG = lastlon; 
}

// JSON url
public static final String API_GET_VEHICLE = "http://example.com/";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity);

    // ListView reference
    mLinearListView = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.linear_listview);

    Log.d(TAG, "tes : " + Access.API_GET_VEHICLE);

    ArrayList<ItemList> mItemListArray=new ArrayList<ItemList>();
    pSubItemArrayList=new ArrayList<SubCategory>();
    pProductArrayList=new ArrayList<Product>();

    List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();

    ServiceHandler sh = new ServiceHandler();

    // Making a request to url and getting response
    String jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(API_GET_VEHICLE , ServiceHandler.GET);

    // Check your log cat for JSON response
    Log.d("Vehicle JSON: ", "> " + jsonStr);


        try { 
        Divi = new JSONArray(jsonStr);
            // looping through All data
            for (int i = 0; i < Divi.length(); i++) {

                JSONObject c = Divi.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item values in variable
                setDivID(c.getString(DIV_ID));
                setDivName(c.getString(DIV_NAME)) ;

                SDiv = new JSONArray();
                //if (SDiv != null) {
                JSONArray SDiv = c.getJSONArray("SubDivision");
                for (int j=0; j<SDiv.length(); j++) {

                    JSONObject sub = SDiv.getJSONObject(j);

                    setSubdivID(sub.getString(SUBDIV_ID));
                    setSubdivName(sub.getString(SUBDIV_NAME));

                    Vehic = new JSONArray();
                    //if (Vehic != null) {
                    JSONArray Vehic = sub.getJSONArray("Vehicle");
                    for (int k=0; k<Vehic.length(); k++) 
                    {
                        JSONObject veh = Vehic.getJSONObject(k);

                        setnoPol(veh.getString(TAG_NOPOL));
                        setLocate(veh.getString(TAG_LOCATION));
                        setLastlon(veh.getString(TAG_LONG));
                }
                }
            }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.d("handle","JSONException Handled");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    pProductArrayList.add(new Product(getDivisionName(), pSubItemArrayList));
    pSubItemArrayList.add(new SubCategory(getSubdivName(), mItemListArray));
    mItemListArray.add(new ItemList(getnoPol(), getLocate(), getLastlon()));
    mItemListArray.add(new ItemList(getnoPol(), getLocate(), getLastlon()));
```

My problem is i have a warning on logcat. The 'value for 00571564' is on TAG_NOPOL, but why it able to showing the json data. Here my logcat

```
12-29 11:30:37.064: D/Vehicle JSON:(1246): > [{"DivisionID":"2c0e9dc1-a6a7-4e38-b93f-2e158c4deffd","DivisionName":"Telto","SubDivision":[{"SubDivisionID":"70c3ac53-eec6-4ca3-94aa-5a73109597f6","SubDivisionName":"FM2200","Vehicle":[{"Nopol":"00571564","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8082176,"LastLat":-6.2304376,"Location":"TULODONG ATAS-CPN Office","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848020936627","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.808208,"LastLat":-6.230759,"Location":"SENOPATI-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848020975237","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8082368,"LastLat":-6.230522,"Location":"SENOPATI-CPN Office","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848020990939","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8082112,"LastLat":-6.2305936,"Location":"SENOPATI-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021061888","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.80819138805734,"LastLat":-6.2301388574162653,"Location":"TULODONG ATAS-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021107434","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8082816,"LastLat":-6.2305712,"Location":"SENOPATI-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021109521","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":116.0763392,"LastLat":-8.5707216,"Location":"-","Kecamatan":"AMPENAN","Kabupaten":"KOTA MATARAM"},{"Nopol":"352848021112277","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":2.0,"LastLon":106.808208,"LastLat":-6.230759,"Location":"SENOPATI-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021112285","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.808208,"LastLat":-6.230759,"Location":"SENOPATI-APOTIK SENOPATI","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021279498","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8081792,"LastLat":-6.2305036,"Location":"","Kecamatan":"","Kabupaten":""},{"Nopol":"352848021405093","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.80832,"LastLat":-6.2306388,"Location":"SENOPATI-parkiran motor CPN","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"352848021414749","LastUpdate":"Oct 29 2013  2:22PM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8083136,"LastLat":-6.2305384,"Location":"SENOPATI-parkiran motor CPN","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"570388","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.6985856,"LastLat":-6.0790272,"Location":"DESA KOSAMBI-","Kecamatan":"KOSAMBI","Kabupaten":"KAB. TANGERANG"},{"Nopol":"570393","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8082688,"LastLat":-6.2306024,"Location":"SENOPATI-parkiran motor CPN","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"570399","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":107.101568,"LastLat":-6.297048,"Location":"KALIMANTAN-Rute_001","Kecamatan":"CIKARANG BARAT","Kabupaten":"KAB. BEKASI"},{"Nopol":"570739","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8084096,"LastLat":-6.230694,"Location":"SENOPATI-parkiran motor CPN","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"570846","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.6987584,"LastLat":-6.0790624,"Location":"DESA KOSAMBI-","Kecamatan":"KOSAMBI","Kabupaten":"KAB. TANGERANG"},{"Nopol":"571155","LastUpdate":"Oct 25 2013  3:46PM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.8083264,"LastLat":-6.2305592,"Location":"SENOPATI-parkiran motor CPN","Kecamatan":"KEBAYORAN BARU","Kabupaten":"JAKARTA SELATAN"},{"Nopol":"571464","LastUpdate":"Oct 10 2010 10:10AM","LastSpeed":0.0,"LastLon":106.80819138805734,"LastL
12-29 11:30:37.134: D/handle(1246): JSONException Handled
12-24 10:21:10.068: W/System.err(1487): org.json.JSONException: No value for 00571564
12-24 10:21:10.068: W/System.err(1487):     at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:354)
12-24 10:21:10.068: W/System.err(1487):     at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:510)
12-24 10:21:10.068: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
12-24 10:21:10.079: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
12-24 10:21:10.079: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
12-24 10:21:10.079: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
12-24 10:21:10.079: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
12-24 10:21:10.079: W/System.err(1487):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-24 10:21:10.092: W/System.err(1487):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
12-24 10:21:10.092: W/System.err(1487):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
12-24 10:21:10.092: W/System.err(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-24 10:21:10.092: W/System.err(1487):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
12-24 10:21:10.092: W/System.err(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
12-24 10:21:10.098: W/System.err(1487):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
12-24 10:21:10.098: W/System.err(1487):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: can you post full logcat

Comment: Can you post your JSON?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is you are using TAG constants to set the values inside

I.E: TAG_NOPOL will hold the JSON-KEY of that field which is "Nopol"

later, on your code, you set the value of that tag with the value from JSON

`setnoPol(veh.getString(TAG_NOPOL));`

as you can see:

```
public void setnoPol (String nopol) {
    this.TAG_NOPOL = nopol;
}
```

setnoPol() stores the value in the TAG variable...

notice `veh.getString(TAG_NOPOL)` this will cause ==> `setnoPol(veh.getString("00571564"));`  and you will get that error...

this is WRONG.
the tag will hold the key name of the field, another field in the class should hold the value.

so next time you try to read from jsonObject with TAG_NOPOL, it will try to find a value in json with the key `00571564` which is a **VALUE** so here you get the error.

best practice is to define your KEY-Names (TAGS) as final

```
private static final String TAG_NOPOL = "Nopol";
```

and you need to have other class members that holds the values for those keys.
so you read from jsonObject using the TAG constant and store in the proper class member.

your class should look like:

```
private static final String DIV_ID = "DivisionID";
private static final String DIV_NAME = "DivisionName";
private static final String SUBDIV_ID = "SubDivisionID";
private static final String SUBDIV_NAME = "SubDivisionName";
private static final String TAG_NOPOL = "Nopol";
private static final String TAG_LOCATION = "Location";
private static final String TAG_LONG = "LastLon";

//NO SETTERS GETTERS FOR TAG VALUES (THEY ARE FINAL)


private String divId = "";
private String divName = "";
private String subDivId = "";

//GETTERS AND SETTER HERE FOR THE variables above (Not for the TAG_xx)
public void setDivId(String id){
    this.divId = id;
}
:
:
:
```